# preRenderView not called before f:View locale attribute

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JAAS form based login page. The users can either login via the form or via `GET` parameters of the URL.

To do a programmatically login I added an event listener for `preRenderView`. I also added a `f:view` so I could set the correct locale.

I noticed that the method `activeLanguage` (from the `f:view` `locale` attribute) is called before `tryLoginWithRequestParams`. (Note: Everything still works I'm just not happy that my `programmaticLogin` method is not called first.)

Why is my method in the `preRenderView` event not called first? Well I guess it's only effectively called before the `render` method of the view (?).

But then how can I call the programmatic login method first (before "all" other stuff)?

The relevant code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginController.tryLoginWithRequestParams}" />
    </f:metadata>
    <f:view locale="#{translationController.activeLanguage.language}">
```

PS: Maybe stack should introduce a `BalusC` tag ... :P

PPS: moving `f:metadata` inside the `f:view` doesn't help.

Comment: The locale resolved when the view is build, not on render time. You can create a view with no markup that do the login and then redirect to the view and then in the other view resolve the locale. I don't know if that could work in your case, but it is an option.

Comment: no this could unfortunately not work, since I want the users to be able to switch the language on the login page. I guess what could do is create a second "dummy" loginpage ( `login2.xhtml`) where I just do the programmatic login and then on fail redirect to the normal login-page. But maybe there's a cleaner/better way.